# Is it ok or reccomended to use Basic access authentication in addition to BCrypt to prevent unauthorized users from acsessing the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, basic-authentication, bcrypt

This is a very conceptual question, but as the title implies I am using Basic access authentication to prevent unauthorized access to a server, which is not very secure by itself. However, I am encrypting the correct username:password combo with Bcrypt before sending the username:password to the server. Will this prevent unauthorized access? I have made several web pages and servers before using Node.js. However, this is my first time creating one which might be used by the general populous rather than just being for fun/experience, so I am unaware of most of the security vulnerabilities to look out for.

I am aware users can inspect element to get headers but because I am using BCrypt the `authentication` header is equivalent to: `JDJhJDEwJFZxSTRrNnZqL0pXYndSS1djOUk4Q3VybWRlbUppUUJTc0VkbWlpZEMwNDRDLnAxRWR5MTAuOiQyYSQxMCRwRkRMTGpTYXlLMUZiV0hsUEFONHd1RnBIN3Vwd0tWc2pCNlJWR1NreHBmbm0ydzNVVWtSdQ` which decoded to UTF-8 is to: `$2a$10$VqI4k6vj/JWbwRKWc9I8CurmdemJiQBSsEdmiidC044C.p1Edy10.:$2a$10$pFDLLjSayK1FbWHlPAN4wuFpH7upwKVsjB6RVGSkxpfnm2w3UUkRu`

Comment: is the encryption done in the client side (browser) code?

Comment: are you hashing or encrypting?  sending a hashed password provides no additional security.

Comment: How does the client works? Is it a JS client(React, Angular...)? Does it know the secret to encrypt the credentials? Have you been thinking in any other strategies, such as JWT Token or client certificate?

Comment: @JaromandaX everything is done on the server, the server only sends JSON data to the client

Comment: @jdigital encrypting a hash, I think. I take the username, for example, encrypt it using BCrypt, then convert that into Base64, and then send it to the server.

Comment: @DiogoSilvério Thier is no client the only thing seen by the client is JSON data, eventually, my server (serverA) will be called by another server (serverB) to retrieve data and store it on serverB, I looked into other strategies, but decided to ask this question first before I rewrote anything, a client cert probably would not be practical in my situation

Comment: all you've done is obscured the username and password.  anyone intercepting the message will gain access to the credentials and this would allow unauthorized access.

Comment: @jdigital, I am also forcing https, to use SSL, would that prevent them from accessing the credintials